# ASP MVC site reverted to older DLL after a few hours

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dll

I performed a site deployment yesterday, and this morning while checking my ELMAH log I noticed several "Method Not Found" exceptions coming through. Basically, in this deployment, we have removed some parameters from a class' constructor and modified all calling code to not pass the extra parameters (the code won't compile if we're passing more than it can take...)

My deployment process was as follows:

- stop the application pool
- ensure w3wp process is stopped
- Deleted the entire contents of C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root
- copy over new DLLs into the site's bin/ folder
- restart application pool

What's weirder is that we deployed at 12:30pm but didn't see the first exception until close to 8pm. I can see that several users actually went through the "path" of the site which ended up not working at 8pm.

I checked the contents of the ASP temporary folder and I can see 2 copies of the problem DLL - one is a version from 21st October and the other from yesterday. I've checked the GAC and it's not in there neither.

I'm really confused what's happened. Why hasn't it loaded my site's DLLs from its "bin" folder? Why has it reverted to an older one after some random amount of time?

I've never experienced any issues like this with Webforms based sites.

**Edit1**: I've fixed this by stopping the application pool, deleting the contents of temporary ASP files and then starting the application pool again.

**Edit2**:
I just checked the ELMAH log and the same error has came through yesterday. I do not understand how. I've deleted the Temporary ASP files folder and saw that no DLLs were in there

I just looked into that folder again and the old DLL from 20th October is inside there. I do not understand where this has came from. We replaced the offending DLL during the publish, while the Application Pool was stopped and the Temporary ASP Files folder emptied.

Comment: Don't you sign DLLs? Version them? Why don't you use Publish facilities?

Comment: No we don't sign or version them. You mean publish from inside visual studio? We're running a load-balanced site so our deployments involves publishing to server A after taking it out of LB rotation so that the customer doesn't see any downtime. I've ran another site for 2.5 years (WebForms though, not MVC) and have never seen any issue like this when replacing DLLs during publishes.

Comment: @StevenSproat - there is no difference between MVC and WebForms in this regard.  Nor does your response explain why you can't use the publish function.  You can still take one server out of your load balancer, publish to it, then bring it back in while taking the second server out and then publishing to that.

Comment: Okay fair enough, I don't see what using Publish accomplishes versus what we do? We're using Entity Framework so we have to do some manual things to get any new migrations applied while one server is out of rotation.

Comment: I think the only thing I may be missing is an iis reset of sorts. I still don't see what Publish does that my manual process does not?

Comment: This doesn't seem logical, is there a backup process of some sort that does a restore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue: there's a *plugins* folder which contained a copy of the problem DLL (with the older version than the newest one in the website's *bin* folder). It seemed to be randomly choosing this DLL to run instead of the newest one - ~6 hours after clearing *Temporary ASP Files* the issue would re-appear. Since updating the correct files now it seems to have sorted itself and the problem hasn't happened overnight. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

The solution which you employ is baffling enough and extremely hard to track its problems, Since we have inheritance hierarchies when using resources like DLLs, Configuration files and etc ... . So, You have to use Visual Studio publisher tool to avoid deployment hardships. **Note** that *ASP.NET MVC is "bin-deployable" - there is nothing too clever to set up on the server either - just point the wildcard `ISAPI` filter to ASP.NET*

Answer (score 0):

When you add a reference of another assembly in your project you can specify whether the assembly should copy it locally every time or you compile your project or not.

In the References >> properties of the assembly window either change the path to the new version's path or set the "**Copy Local**" property to False, it could be the reason for this issue and if you don't copy the assembly locally then it could lead to this issue.